# Timing a loop with nanosleep() in C

Tags: c, linux, time

So I'm trying to get each iteration of an infinite while loop to take `nsec_ival_tspec.tv_nsec` nanoseconds. What I do is this:

```
while(!done){
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start_loop_time);

    ...

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end_loop_time);
    timespec_sum(&start_loop_time, &nsec_ival_tspec, &exp_end);
    timespec_diff(&end_loop_time, &exp_end, &diff_tspec);
    if(diff_tspec.tv_sec >=0 && diff_tspec.tv_nsec>=0){
        nanosleep(&diff_tspec, NULL);
    }
```

where timespec_sum/diff are void-output functions whose third argument gets overwritten by the result. They work as expected so no worries.

This scheme overshoots for some reason, by six digits of nanosecs.

```
0004.139  Expected iteration time: 2000000 nsec
0004.142  Mean iteration time:     2188123 nsec
```

Added a check to see if nanosleep overslept.

```
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tmpclock);
    printf("Expected time after sleep: %ld\n", tmpclock.tv_nsec + diff_tspec.tv_nsec);
    if(diff_tspec.tv_sec >=0 && diff_tspec.tv_nsec>0){
        nanosleep(&diff_tspec, &error_spec);
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tmpclock);
    printf("Real time after sleep:     %ld\n", tmpclock.tv_nsec);
```

and yep it does. By roughly 10^5 nanoseconds. Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Comment: This is expected. `sleep` and `nanosleep` have only *one* guarantee: the process will sleep for **at least** the time specified. It is impossible to do better than this, because once your process "sleeps" it is in the end of the OS scheduler, so there is no way of guaranteeing a very fine precision. The scheduler typically let processes run for order of milli seconds or so.

Comment: Oh wow then calling it nanosleep is surely false advertising!!

Comment: Linux is not a RTOS

Comment: @Bakuriu Actually, it doesn't even guarantee that. The process can still be waken up by signals, so the correct usage is to wrap sleep() in a while loop and check that the required time has elapsed.